# Java API for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

What is in your experience a good Java API for [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)?

I am searching for something with annotation based mapping of Java POJOs to MongoDB resources and a decent query abstraction layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Morphia
http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

It works really well (haven't encountered any problems with it), eventhough it's still pre-1.0.

Comment: Can we use Morphia with gridfs?

Answer (score 3):

The Spring data framework might be an alternative

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.core

Objects look like this

```
@Document
public class Person {

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

  @Indexed
  private Integer ssn;

  private String firstName;

  @Indexed
  private String lastName;

}
```

Querying can be done via automagical Repository interfaces, or with mongoTemplate which looks like this:

```
List<Person> result = mongoTemplate.find(query(where("age").lt(50).and("accounts.balance").gt(1000.00d)), Person.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you might want to try out their statically typed queries. I've heard they are quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Used both on two different projects. Started out using Morphia but lack of support by main developer limited us. Even though 10gen hired Morphia developer, support for Morphia seemed to be wavering.

When I asked 10gen folks about their plans for Morphia I got no clear response. We switched to spring data on other project and API seems more complete and better docs and community.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the lightest and well documented is Jongo (jongo.org). It can be a good and fast option.